# Stacking Pandas Dataframe without dropping row

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I have a dataframe like this:

```
0 0 0 3 0 0
0 7 8 9 1 0
0 4 5 2 4 0
```

My code to stack it:

```
dt = dataset.iloc[:,0:7].stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_frame()
dt['variable'] = pandas.Categorical(dt.index).codes+1
dt.rename(columns={0:index_column_name}, inplace=True)
dt.set_index(index_column_name, inplace=True)
dt['variable'] = numpy.sort(dt['variable'])
```

However, **it drops the first row when I'm stacking it**, and I want to keep the headers / first row, how would I achieve this?

In essence, I'm losing the data from the first row (a.k.a column headers) and  I want to keep it.

Desired Output:

```
value,variable
0 1
0 1
0 1
0 2
7 2
4 2
0 3
8 3
5 3
3 4
9 4
2 4
0 5
1 5
4 5
0 6
0 6
0 6
```

Current output:

```
value,variable
0 1
0 1
7 2
4 2
8 3
5 3
9 4
2 4
1 5
4 5
0 6
0 6
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @TylerWayne I'm confident we can get you an answer, but you need to do a bit more for us in explaining what it is you want.

Comment: I have added more information to my post.

Comment: is this df.melt() ?

Comment: or maybe `df.values.flatten('F')`

Comment: I think it might have to do with this actually;      ```dt.rename(columns={0:index_column_name}, inplace=True)``` and ```dt.set_index(index_column_name, inplace=True)```. If I set inplace to false, then it doesn't create the new columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `df.melt` as @WeNYoBen mentioned?

```
print(df)

   1  2  3  4  5  6
0  0  0  0  3  0  0
1  0  7  8  9  1  0
2  0  4  5  2  4  0

print(df.melt())

   variable  value
0         1      0
1         1      0
2         1      0
3         2      0
4         2      7
5         2      4
6         3      0
7         3      8
8         3      5
9         4      3
10        4      9
11        4      2
12        5      0
13        5      1
14        5      4
15        6      0
16        6      0
17        6      0
```